# What 110V breaker to use to supply a 220V supply to a 100A sub-panel

Tags: subpanel

I have a shed that is wired for the following : two 110V lights, 2 110V outlets + a 220V outlet for a Welder (60A). I am trying to figure out what size breakers to use to supply power. I will be coming off the panel that supplies power to my house. Under the meter panel there are 4 110V spades for breakers, one is being used, a breaker that supplies power to my instant hot water tank leaving three available spots for breakers. The panel also contains breakers to the main panel to the house, I see a breaker that says 200A, so I guess the house is supplied with a 200A power supply?

Comment: Need a double pole breaker(220/240v depending) 60 to 100A.  Show picture of panel in question, in case something different.  Would suggest using a Electrician.

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing main panel, including any labeling on the inside of its door?

Comment: Please educate yourself a lot more, or choose not to do this job, other than writing a check for someone competent to do it. You appear to be dangerously ignorant of basic details to be connecting anything to a main panel. Reading a few postings here will not constitute an adequate eduction.